# Address field localization by both culture and UI culture in Asp.Net MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, localization

I have an address model type that includes these fields:

```
public string CountyState { get; set; }
public string PostZip { get; set; }
```

I'm using a customised version of the `DisplayNameAttribute` (written before the .Net 4 `DisplayAttribute` gave us localization) which enables localization of the display name of these two fields.

So naturally the local `en-GB` translation of these are `"County"` and `"Post Code`", while for `en-US` they are of course `"State"` and `"Zip Code"`.

However, my MVC website is displaying payment pages for different businesses in different locations which must also be able to be translated into other languages.  Thus, the UI culture might be `en-GB` but the address fields should still show `"State"` and `"Zip Code"` if the payment is being taken for an American business (back-end culture of `en-US`).

Thus, it would seem that a single Resource Type/Key localised look-up for these display fields is not enough.  I *do not* want to use different model types based on country, and I *do not* want to be writing different Html - both solutions will become umanageable as my site grows since businesses etc would be added via database.

My site is already using `CurrentCulture` to indicate the business' default culture (used for formatting currency of course), and I'm using `CurrentUICulture` to signify the user's culture; so I've considered what I think is a slightly wacky solution:

Use a string localised by `CurrentCulture` to lookup a resource key for the field - e.g. `ResourceName_Display_Address_PostZip`.  When `en-GB` this would return `DisplayName_GB_PostCode`, but when `en-US` it would return `DisplayName_US_ZipCode`.

Now use `CurrentUICulture` to lookup the localised version of that.

I would then have to write an attribute that can wrap this logic up so that it's compatible with MVC.

A good solution?  Or have I missed something blindingly obvious!?

Comment: Does your customized version of `DisplayNameAttribute ` have an associated `CurrentCulture`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is what I've done.

I've had to make this code more local to my specific project because it relies on the resource class being passed in having a public static property `ResourceManager` of the type `System.Resources.ResourceManager`.  This is true for the class generated by VS' own strongly typed resource accessor classes (generated from .resx files) and so I think it probably qualifies as reusable.  It uses this so it can specify the culture to be used when looking up the string(s).

It first does a resource lookup (using `CurrentCulture`) for the resource name to be used for the model property's text; then it pumps that string back into another resource lookup (using `CurrentUICulture`) to get the actual display name to be used.

I've replaced all the error checking with TODOs to keep it succinct.

In the end I derived directly from `DisplayNameAttribute` because this new pattern didn't sit nicely with the code I used (ripped off from `RequiredAttribute`) to get UICulture-based resource strings for my own existing customised attribute.  I don't like the class name but can't think of anything better right now.

```
public class CultureDrivenDisplayNameAttribute : DisplayNameAttribute
{
  private readonly string _displayName = null;
  public CultureDrivenDisplayNameAttribute(Type resourceType,
    string resourceNameLookup)
  {
    //TODO: check for null args

    //get the ResourceManager member
    var prop = resourceType.GetProperty(
      "ResourceManager", 
      System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public 
        | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static);

    //TODO: check for null or unexpected property type.

    System.Resources.ResourceManager resourceManager = 
      prop.GetValue(null, null) as System.Resources.ResourceManager;

    //TODO: check for null

    //ResourceManager is used as it lets us specify the culture - we need this
    //to be able to lookup first on Culture, then by UICulture.
    string finalResourceName = 
      resourceManager.GetString(resourceNameLookup, 
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture);

    //TODO: check for null/whitespace resource value

    _displayName = resourceManager.GetString(finalResourceName, 
      Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture);
    //TODO: check for null display name
  }

  public override string DisplayName
  {
    get
    {
      return _displayName;
    }
  }
}
```

So, now I decorate my address model's PostZip/CountyState properties as follows:

```
[CultureDrivenDisplayName(typeof(StringResources), 
  "ResourceName_AddressDetails_CountyState")]
public string CountyState { get; set; }

[CultureDrivenDisplayName(typeof(StringResources), 
  "ResourceName_AddressDetails_PostZip")]
public string PostZip { get; set; }
```

And then, in my neutral resource file:

```
ResourceName_AddressDetails_CountyState: "DisplayName_AddressDetails_CountyState"
ResourceName_AddressDetails_PostZip: "DisplayName_AddressDetails_PostZip"
DisplayName_AddressDetails_CountyState: "County/State"
DisplayName_AddressDetails_PostZip: "Post/Zip Code"
```

So if I haven't set up resource files for a given Culture, the address will display text that is reasonable.

But in my en-GB resource file:

```
ResourceName_AddressDetails_CountyState: "DisplayName_AddressDetails_CountyState_GB"
ResourceName_AddressDetails_PostZip: "DisplayName_AddressDetails_PostZip_GB"
DisplayName_AddressDetails_CountyState_GB: "County"
DisplayName_AddressDetails_PostZip_GB: "Post Code"
```

So now, regardless of UI culture, an english site will always display 'County' or 'Post Code'; but a UI culture is able to provide it's own local translation of both phrases if it wishes by simply defining localised versions of the `_GB` suffixed resource strings.

I've also realised that I might need to do the same for whole pages, so am looking at extending the Razor and Aspx view engines to support Culture and UI Culture-based versions automatically using subfolders.  the only issue then is how to interpret the folder `/en-GB/` - is that relating to the back-end or front-end culture!

Answer (score 1):

This is just pseudo-code. I'm not in a place to test and debug right now. But if your customized version of `DisplayNameAttribute` have an associated `CurrentCulture` you should be able to write and extension method similar to this:

```
    public static string GetLocalizedDisplayName<TProperty>(Expression<Func<TProperty>> e)
    {
        var modelType = ((MemberExpression)e.Body).Member.ReflectedType.GetType();
        var classProperties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(modelType).OfType<CustomAttribute>;
        var prop = from property in classProperties
                   where property.CultureInfo == CultureInfo.CurrentCulture
                   select property;

        return prop != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(prop.DisplayName) ? prop.DisplayName : member.Member.Name;
    }
```

Comment: Ah yes, that's an interesting solution, and quite expressive too

Comment: Although I would like to be able to plug this in directly to MVC's existing `Html.LabelFor` stuff without needing to override those templates (admittedly that's a small issue)

Comment: You cannot override an extension method. 

Its a little hacky, but if you are opposed to changing all the `Html.LabelFor()` you could do this
However instance methods take priority. See [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/e42f1511-39e7-4fed-9e56-0cc19c00d33d) If you partial class the HtmlHelper you may be able to make an instance method that does what you want and you would not have to rewrite all the method calls

Comment: Ah you miss my point - `Html.LabelFor` uses meta data to get the display name of the property to be rendered which, in turn, reflects the attributes; any solution must present the correct display name according to the current culture/ui-culture pairing.  Your solution above could be incorporated into a custom meta data provider that changes how it looks for the display name.  My own solution (I've started work on it and will post when done) requires only changing the attribute itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceType=typeof(Languages.Resource),ErrorMessageResourceName="PostZip")]
[Display(ResourceType=typeof(Languages.Resource),Name="PostZip")]
public string PostZip { get; set; }
```

Now Create different .resx files for different locals
eg

Name=PostZip |  Value= Zip Code   [for en-US]

Name=PostZip |  Value= Post Code   [for en-GB]

---inside controller-----

```
 //whatever logic you are looking for, now  set culture manually

CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("hi");
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(ci.Name);
```

----------inside view--------------

```
 @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PostZip)
```

refer  http://haacked.com/archive/2009/12/12/localizing-aspnetmvc-validation.aspx this link too.

Comment: Sorry this doesn't give me anything I don't already have - localising a particular piece of text per UI culture isn't a problem; it's localising a particular term that in itself is localised (e.g. localising Post/Zip for an address to UK/English according to backend first and then selecting the user's local translation of that word (e.g. French user on American site seeing the french for 'Zip Code'; possibly 'Code Zip')

Comment: could you explain this term "it's localising a particular term that in itself is localised" a bit more

Comment: Okay, so given an address model with properties Address1-4, Post/Zip, Country (typical international address).  The display names of these fields change not only their text but their *meaning* depending upon culture (`Thread.CurrentCulture`) before any local translation (`Thread.CurrentUICulture`) is taken into account.  So if `CurrentCulture` is `en-US`, Post/Zip is a 'Zip Code' whereas if it were `en-GB` it would be a 'Post Code'; but then that phrase, in turn, needs to be translated to the local language according to `CurrentUICulture`...

Comment: ...in this case regardless of UI culture we would display 'Zip Code' for both `en-US` and `en-GB` UI cultures when the back-end culture is `en-US`; or 'Post Code' for both if the back-end culture is `en-GB'. With `DisplayAttribute`, or indeed my custom attribute, both hang off UI culture only for translation, so a user with US-English set as their UI culture will always see `Zip Code` even if the page is capturing a UK address.  Equally other languages may have their own local translations for these words that change depending upon whether it starts off as either Zip or Post Code

Comment: i have added some code + a link lets see that works or not for you

Comment: thanks - but I need to be able to maintain the separate Culture and UI Culture throughout the request - I'm using Culture to format the correct currency value (according to the business' needs)